# Upgraded Kibana and Elasticsearch to v8.9.2, Kibana is not starting, Error: Not enough active copies to meet shard count of [ALL] (have 1, needed 2)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, bitnami, sharding

I recently upgraded Elasticsearch and Kibana to v8.9.2 using Bitnami Helm chart on my Kubernetes AWS EKS cluster. Elasticsearch is running fine with 3 nodes but Kibana is restarting again and again as it is failing to start as it is terminating with exit code 1.

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
FATAL Error: Unable to complete saved object migrations for 
the [.kibana_task_manager] index. Error: [{"type":
"unavailable_shards_exception","reason":"[.kibana_task_manager_8.5.1_001][0] 
Not enough active copies to meet shard count of [ALL] 
(have 1, needed 2). Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest 
[[.kibana_task_manager_8.5.1_001][0]] containing [26] requests]"}, ...]
```

I have already checked the following 4 discussions but none of them worked:

- https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/127136
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/not-enough-active-copies-to-meet-write-consistency-of-all/44663/2
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/not-enough-active-copies-to-meet-write-consistency-of-quorum-have-2-needed-3/59980
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-server-is-not-ready-yet-unavailable-shards-exception/302459

What is the actual issue? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my 3 Elasticsearch master nodes pods and containers and all were running fine but when I checked the Elasticsearch cluster health, it was `yellow` and all of the shards were `unassigned_shards`.

Then I did some research and found this really good article by Elasticsearch: [Elastic Docs › Elasticsearch Guide [8.10] › Troubleshooting › Fix common cluster issues › Red or yellow cluster status](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/red-yellow-cluster-status.html#red-yellow-cluster-status)

One of the causes were related to [Freeing up or increasing disk space](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/red-yellow-cluster-status.html#fix-cluster-status-disk-space) which stated:

> Elasticsearch uses a low disk watermark to ensure data nodes have enough disk space for incoming shards. By default, Elasticsearch does not allocate shards to nodes using more than 85% of disk space.

So when I looked at the logs of the container of the pod of one of the Elasticsearch master nodes, I found the following: `low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][elasticsearch-master-1][/bitnami/elasticsearch/data] free: 196gb[19.9%], replicas will not be assigned to this node`

**And then after deleting some of the very old unwanted indices, free disk space increased and Elasticsearch started allocating shards and after a few minutes, Kibana was up and running fine and the cluster health changed to `green` as well.**